# Meta Query - Display display vehicles for dealer1 & dealer2, sort by dealership & condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a meta query which displays result if key 'dealership' is equal to either dealer1 or dealer2 and then sort it by condition, used first & demo second.

So far I've been using this code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('vehicle'),
  'post_status' => 'publish',   
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => 'dealership',
        'value' => 'dealer1',
        'compare' => '='
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'dealership',
        'value' => 'dealer2',
        'compare' => '='
      ),
  ),
  'meta_key' => 'condition',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value', //meta_value_num or meta_value
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

The above code works perfectly fine, however, I want change the sort order so that it display vehicles in the following order:

1) Dealer1's Used Vehicles
2) Dealer1's Demo Vehicles
3) Dealer2's Used Vehicles
4) Dealer2's Demo Vehicles

So I need to sort the results by dealership and condition.

I have tried several variations but none of the are giving me the results I'm after, most are not working at all.

I suspect this could be achieved using this type of query:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('vehicle'), 
  'post_status' => 'publish', 
  'posts_per_page' => 10, 
  'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'branchsort' => array(
            'key'     => 'dealership',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'demosort' => array(
            'key'     => 'condition',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'branchsort' => 'ASC',
        'demosort' => 'DESC',
    ),
);
```

However I've been unable to get this query to only display result for dealer1 & dealer2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Willem

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit more tinkering and reading up, I came up with this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
// Query arguments
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('vehicle'),
  'post_status' => 'publish',   
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        'branch' => array(
            'key' => 'dealership',
            'value' => array ( 'dealer1', 'dealer2' ),
        ),
        'condition' => array(
            'key' => 'condition',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'dealership' => 'DESC',
        'condition' => 'DESC',
    ),
);
```

Seems to do the trick, if anyone has a better way of doing it, let me know.